# Установка CMS joomla

Tags: joomla, установка

Устанавливаю первый раз, везде в "обучалках" есть значения для выбора типа MySql и т.д. Но у меня нет ничего и естественно ничего не могу настроить.

[image: Нет значений для выбора]

Если оставить так то ошибку выдает
[image: Ошибка]

БД MySQL8 находится на сервере в локальной сети. Пробовал в версиях 3.9, 3.8.11, 3.8.12, тоже самое. Крутится это все на nginx. Как настроить подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Чего товарищи. Никто не знает что ли как это решается?(

Comment: Смотрите решение похожей проблемы на странице: [How can I enable the MySQLi extension in PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424982/how-can-i-enable-the-mysqli-extension-in-php-7)